# Varying enums in Java being accessed by common method

Tags: java, android, generics, enums

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a generic method that can take many different kinds of enums. I'm looking for a way to do it how I'm going to describe, or any other way a person might think of.

I've got a base class, and many other classes extend off that. In each of those classes, I want to have an enum called `Includes` like this:

```
public enum Includes {
    VENDOR ("Vendor"),
    OFFERS_CODES ("OffersCodes"),
    REMAINING_REDEMPTIONS ("RemainingRedemptions");

    private String urlParam;

    Includes(String urlParam) {
        this.urlParam = urlParam;
    }

    public String getUrlParam() {
        return urlParam;
    }
}
```

I've got a method that takes in a generic class that extends from BaseClass, and I want to be able to also pass any of the includes on that class to the method, and be able to access the methods on the enum, like this:

```
ApiHelper.Response<Offer> offer = apiHelper.post(new Offer(), Offer.Includes.VENDOR);

public <T extends BaseClass> Response<T> post(T inputObject, Includes... includes) {

    ArrayList<String> urlParams = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Include include : includes){
        urlParams.add(include.getUrlParam());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is there a way to be able to pass in all the different kinds of enums, or is there a better way to do this?

---EDIT---

I've added an interface to my enum, but how can I generify my method? I've got this:

```
public <T extends BaseClass> Response<T> post(Offer inputObject, BaseClass.Includes includes) {

    for (Enum include : includes){
        if (include instanceof Offer.Includes){
            ((Offer.Includes) include).getUrlParam();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I get an error on `apiHelper.post(new Offer(), Offer.Includes.VENDOR);` saying the second param must be BaseClass.Includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums can implement interfaces, so you can create an interface with these methods that you'd like to be able to call:

```
interface SomeBaseClass {
  String getUrlParam();
  void setUrlParam(String urlParam);
}
```

and then your enum can implement this interface:

```
public enum Includes implements SomeBaseClass {
  VENDOR ("Vendor"),
  OFFERS_CODES ("OffersCodes"),
  REMAINING_REDEMPTIONS ("RemainingRedemptions");

  private String urlParam;

  Includes(String urlParam) {
    this.urlParam = urlParam;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUrlParam() {
    return urlParam;
  }

  @Override
  public void setUrlParam(String urlParam) {
    this.urlParam = urlParam;
  }
}
```

If you want to get really fancy, it's possible to restrict subtypes of the interface to enums, but the generic type declaration will be pretty ugly (thus hard to understand and maintain) and probably won't provide any "real" benefits.

---

*Unrelated note regarding this design:* it's a pretty strong code smell that the enum instances are mutable. Reconsider why you need that `setUrlParam()` method in the first place.

Comment: The unrelated note alone deserves a +1.

Comment: Good point on the setUrlParam(). Mostly that's just habit from POJOs. Post edited.

Comment: @idratherbeintheair you should make `urlParam` final to avoid the temptation. :)